# Android: using getIntent() only within onCreate?

Tags: android, android-intent, oncreate

In Android (targeting APIs 14-16) I have a `MainActivity` and a `NextActivity`. There is no difficulty using intents to start `NextActivity` from within `MainActivity` if the `getIntent()` method is called inside the `onCreate()` block of `NextActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int data = 7;
        ...
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("data", data);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

public class NextActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final int data = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("data", 7);
        ...
        }
    ...
    }
```

However, since the field `data` is being used inside an anonymous ("inner") class in `NextActivity`, I am compelled to declare it `final`.

I'd prefer not to declare fields `final`, and I can usually avoid doing so if I declare them at the beginning of the class, before `onCreate()` begins. But for some reason, the app crashes when `NextActivity` starts if the `getIntent()` statement appears (without the `final` keyword) outside of `onCreate()`.

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you post a logcat of the crash?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't `getIntent()` before `onCreate()` -- there's simply no `Intent` available at that point. I believe the same is true for anything that requires a `Context`.

Your anonymous inner class can still call `getIntent()`, however, so you don't need to declare this as a variable at all.

Comment: Good point about context. The variable is needed both within the inner class and elsewhere, and I need to be able to modify it. So perhaps I should declare the variable as non-`final` but introduce a second, `final` variable to shepherd the value into the inner class.

Comment: Or declare it as a non-final field in the activity with a getter method. You would be able to call `getData()` from inside or outside the anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question what i understand  is u don't want to declare data as final in next activity..Then y cant u try for this./

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {
    int data=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         data = this.getIntent().getIntExtra("data", 7);
        ...
        }
    ...
    }
```

Try this...

Comment: The compiler requires a type declaration; can't run it without `int`.

Comment: Ah, very nice. You got around the problem perfectly.

Comment: And this is a fine general method.