# getStringExtra() always throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Main activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Secondary.class);

intent.putExtra("name",value);

startActivity(intent);
```

Secondary activity:

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("name")
```

What's wrong here? I've searched a lot without success...

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that getIntent() itself is not returning NULL?

Comment: Ok, getIntent() is returning NULL. How to fix that?

Comment: I am guessing that there is no valid intent at the point that you are calling getIntent().  Are you calling this before onCreate()?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983728/android-using-getintent-only-within-oncreate

Comment: Show us where you set the value of value string variable in Main Activity

Comment: So I can't use Intent in onCreate? It's called in setOnClickListener when the user click the view. Is that the problem?

Comment: No that should not be a problem. Check the answer I provided. Everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered I have an issue in my code it was my fault. It wasn't an Intent problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

In the MainActivity:

```
//Make sure Secondary is an Activity name. Secondary.class.

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Secondary.class);
intent.putExtra("name",value);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the Secondary Activity:

`String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");`

You need to get the bundle first and then extract the string from it.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    bundle.getString("name");
}
```

Both should work. The second one is to check if the bundle is null.

Comment: Initializing variables should be mandatory... or all variables which are not initialized should have a value of 0 in case of string types, and empty in case of uri etc... its just unnecessary (to my primitive mind) as to why this extra work is required... is it for security, because it does not look like its for performane

Answer (score 0):

When you call `putExtra(...)`, make sure the `value` object is a `String`. If you're passing any other object, make sure to explicitly call `value.toString()`, especially if dealing with GUI components.

See here for more information: [Android Intent.getStringExtra() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555750/android-intent-getstringextra-returns-null)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this method times. Just make sure value has a value or initialized.You can use **Log** or     **System.out.println(value);** after **.putExtra** to see(in console tab) if value is null. and in second activity too.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
```

TO this line

```
String value = getIntent().getString("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -->

```
intent.putExtra("name", textView.getText().toString());
```

If the error still occurs, check-in the Second Activity that you are using the right id path...:-

```
value = findViewById(R.id.);
```