# Get Team Code from ViewHolder through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewholder

I'm trying to get team codes for each Premier League team when I click on a particular  team in the League Table in a viewHolder. I've successfully been able to send over the team name and team position through intents from one activity to another. I've hardcoded the team codes to each team in a my Configs Class

I'm not sure as to how to go about fixing this error.

```
public static int getCodeFromName(String teamname) {
        switch (teamname) {
            case "Arsenal FC":
                return 57;
            case "AFC Bournemouth":
                return 1044;
            case "Burnley FC":
                return 328;
            case "Chelsea FC":
                return 61;
            case "Crystal Palace FC":
                return 354;
            case "Hull City FC":
                return 322;
            case "Liverpool FC":
                return 164;
            case "Manchester City FC":
                return 65;
            case "Manchester United FC":
                return 66;
            case "Middlesbrough FC":
                return 343;
            case "Southampton FC":
                return 340;
            case "Swansea City":
                return 72;
            case "Leicester City FC":
                return 338;
            case "Everton FC":
                return 62;
            case "West Ham United FC":
                return 563;
            case "Tottenham Hotspur FC":
                return 73;
            case "Watford FC":
                return 346;
            case "West Bromwich Albion FC":
                return 74;
            case "Sunderland AFC":
                return 71;
            case "Stoke City FC":
                return 70;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

Below is my OnClick method which works for the other two intents(teamName, position)

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int teamCode = Configs.getCodeFromName(teamNameTxt.getText().toString());

        int position = getLayoutPosition(); // gets item position
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("teamName", teamNameTxt.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("position", teamPositionTxt.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("teamCode", teamCode);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

And lastly, in my DetailActivity Class

```
int teamCode = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("teamCode")); //ERROR OCCURS HERE

String PlayersURL = "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/" + teamCode + "/players";

final String teamName = getIntent().getStringExtra("teamName");
String teamPosition = getIntent().getStringExtra("position");


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.team_overview);


    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    if (rv != null) {
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }


    teamNameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teamNameTV);
    teamNameTV.setText("Name: " + teamName);

    teamPositionTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teamPositionTV);
    teamPositionTV.setText("Position : " + teamPosition);


    button_players = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_players);
    button_players.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new PlayerDataDownloader(DetailActivity.this, PlayersURL, rv).execute();
        }
    });
```

The error code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at com.example.oisin.premierleaguesocial.activities.DetailActivity.<init>(DetailActivity.java:26)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you're calling `Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)` on a null object reference. Looking at the code where the error occurs,

```
int teamCode = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("teamCode"));
```

`getStringExtra()` is being called on the return value of `getIntent()`. So this means `getIntent()` is returning null.

This call occurs in a field initializer, outside of any method. This means it gets called before the DetailActivity's constructor (though after the superclass Activity's constructor).

More to the point, [`getIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent())'s doc says "Return the intent that started this activity." But *started* can be a technical term in the [activity's lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). If you look at the life cycle diagram, you can see that *starting* comes after the *creation* of the activity (which is after the instantiation of the Activity object). An activity can be *started*, and even *created*, multiple times by different intents, without its object being *instantiated* more than once. (The first time it's *started*, it will first be *created*, of necessity.) So, while it's not obvious, it makes some sense that "the intent that started this activity" might not be available before *creation* time, even if the superclass activity has been *instantiated*.

Move this initialization code into `onCreate()`, which is where most of your activity setup code should go. Then you can be confident that the activity is already instantiated, the superclass `onCreate()` has already finished, and there should be an intent for `getIntent()` to return.

Comment: @OP see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983728/android-using-getintent-only-within-oncreate