# Dagger - Setting a Dynamic Value to SubComponent Builder

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I want to set a value to my sub-component builder at the time of building it. If simple Dagger 2 is concerned, we can achieve like following:

```
@UserScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {UserModule.class, ActivityBuilder.class, NewEditQuotationModule.class})

public interface UserComponent {
NewEditQuotationComponent.Builder getNewEditQuotationComponent();
void inject(UserManager userManager);

@Subcomponent.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    Builder user(User user);

    UserComponent build();
}}
```

But In case of Dagger Android, Subcomponent and its associated builder is handled by @ContributesAndroidInjector. Dagger Auto generate Subcomponent and its builder even its implementation with the current context.

I want to set some value at the time of building My Dagger Android Subcomponent. I tried by following approach:

```
 @Subcomponent(modules = NewEditQuotationModule.class)
    public interface NewEditQuotationComponent extends AndroidInjector<InquiriesEditNewMainActivity> {


    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<InquiriesEditNewMainActivity> {
        @BindsInstance
        public abstract Builder setName(@Named("My_Name") String name);
    }}

        @Module
    public abstract class NewEditQuotationModule {
        @Binds
        @IntoMap
        @ActivityKey(InquiriesEditNewMainActivity.class)
        abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity>
        bindInquiriesEditNewMainActivityInjectorFactory(NewEditQuotationComponent.Builder builder);

    }
```

I tired to build it by following way:

```
AndroidInjector.Builder androidInjector = MyApplication
                .getApplication()
                .getAppComponent()
                .getApiEndPoint()
                .getApiEndPointComponent()
                .getUserManager()
                .getUserComponent()
                .getNewEditQuotationComponent().setName("My Name");
        androidInjector.seedInstance(this);
        androidInjector.build();
```

But not succeed.
Please let me know

1. How can I set some value at the time of building my component?
2. Where am I wrong in the previous approach?

Comment: @JeffBowman : My scenario is, Some date is coming from previous Activity and the current activity is having 5 fragments and all of them need that data. So I want to provide that data by setting it in the activitie's component at the time of building it. Your suggested approach, I think will not work. Can you please help me out to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dagger.android` works by automatically creating your component in `onCreate`, and needs to work this way because Android is allowed to create your Activity on its own. Pre-creating your AndroidInjector will not work; that is what's wrong with your previous approach.

As I tried to indicate through a duplicate-question vote, the only way for you to set module instance or `@BindsInstance` values in dagger.android is by [overriding the `seedInstance` method in the `AndroidInjector.Builder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371863/dagger-2-10-android-subcomponents-and-builders) that serves as your `@Subcomponent.Builder` as well. This will let you pull values out of the Activity instance and set them in your Activity graph.

Though you could always stash data in a `@Singleton` (ApplicationComponent-scoped) object or VM global variable, you are trying to do the right thing by passing data carefully from Activity to Activity without setting global state. *I think this is the right approach*, but also that *your solution probably will not involve constructing an AndroidInjector explicitly*. Instead, [pass your data through the extras bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/768969/1426891), which is an idiomatic way of transferring parameters and other data into Activities; you can then insert that data into your graph by pulling it out of `getIntent().getExtras()` on your Activity instance in `seedInstance`, since [`getIntent()` should be populated by the time `onCreate(Bundle)` runs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13983728/1426891).

Comment: You are right. Thanks it works.