# How do you use the putExtra() and getExtras() code to get an int value?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

What the title says, I've tried below but it didn't work. Also where should I put the `getExtras()` in `MainActivity.class`? I tried it both outside and inside `OnCreate()` but my app keeps crashing upon startup. I can't find an error with it crashing either.

**SettingsActivity.class**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("isMeasurement", 2);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public int isMeasurement = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("isMeasurement");
```

Comment: It would be available in SettingsActivity

Comment: That doesn't make any sense? There should be some code in MainActivity, and some code in SettingsActivity which is what I have

Comment: You shouldn't call `getIntent()` before `onCreate()` which seems to happen here when you initialize the `public int isMeasurement` field. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984384/6761823

Comment: @Flies is it your data flow like MainActivity->SettingsActivity->MainActivity ????

Comment: Yeah, but I have it all fixed now, thanks guys :) Also, is there something wrong with my questions (like being too dumb or something)? They get downvoted all the time. Not anything to worry about, just curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should pass data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("isMeasurement", 2);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Inside your onCreate

This is how you can retrieve data in MainActivity

```
int isMeasurement = getIntent().getIntExtra("isMeasurement",0); // Here 0 is a default value.It could be anything acc to your requirement
```

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that `getIntent()` should not be called before `onCreate()`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984384/6761823

Comment: I  never mentioned that getIntent() should be called before onCreate. Sorry if my answer was not clear. Have edited it to remove any confusion.

Comment: Yes, but `public int isMeasurement` clearly indicates it's a field that gets evaluated before `onCreate()`. You can't use the `public` modifier like this inside a method.

Comment: you are correct. My mistake for not noticing it before. Thanks for pointing it out @AndrzejZabost

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your getting data in other activity.
The correct way to do is mentioned below :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int isMeasurement = getIntent().getIntExtra("isMeasurement",0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> SettingsActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("isMeasurement", 2);
            startActivity(intent);
```

and

> MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int isMeasurement = getIntent().getIntExtra("isMeasurement",0);
}
```